# How does gdb retrieve the exit code of target program?

Tags: gdb, echo, exit, terminate

Under command line, I know that using echo $? gets me the exit code. In gdb, I use "r" to run through the program and the program terminates, so how does gdb gets this exit code? Any commands inside gdb?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your question about how to print the exit value in GDB (which Tom Tromey answered) or about how GDB gets that value internally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a program exits, gdb sets the convenience variable `$_exitcode` to the exit code.

So given:

```
int main() {
  return 23;
}
```

Running it in gdb, I get:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/q 
[Inferior 1 (process 3677) exited with code 027]
(gdb) print $_exitcode
$1 = 23
```

Comment: [Inferior 1 (process 3677) exited with code 027] <- 027 is 27 octal, which is actually 23 decimal. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24368/unix-history-return-code-octal for reasons...

Answer (score 1):

It just prints exit code at the end of debug session when the program terminates. Or prints `exited normally` for `0` exit code. See test debug session for this test program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return atoi(argv[1]);
}
```

Debug session:

```
[ksemenov@NB824RIH ~]$ gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) r 0
Starting program: /home/ksemenov/a.out 0
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install glibc-2.23.1-10.fc24.x86_64
[Inferior 1 (process 19162) exited normally]
(gdb) r 1
Starting program: /home/ksemenov/a.out 1
[Inferior 1 (process 19166) exited with code 01]
(gdb) r 6
Starting program: /home/ksemenov/a.out 6
[Inferior 1 (process 19167) exited with code 06]
(gdb)
```